# Continually updating values from two sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a savings calculator using two sliders. There are two inputs (number of studens and group size) and two outputs (money savings and time savings). I included an image for reference. The calculations are working but I have to hit refresh in order to see the new answers when I move the slider. Instead I want my answers to change as I move the slider.

I worked from this site but made changes for calculations: http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/

How I want it to look eventually:

[image]

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="layout-slider" style="width: 20%">
        <input id="SliderSingle" type="slider" name="kids" value="20" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            jQuery("#SliderSingle").slider({
                from: 1,
                to: 1000,
                step: 1,
                round: 1,
                format: {
                    format: '0',
                    locale: 'de'
                },
                dimension: ' Kids',
            });
            var numkids = $("#SliderSingle").slider("value");
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-slider" style="width: 20%">
        <input id="Slider" type="slider" name="group" value="20" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            jQuery("#Slider").slider({
                from: 1,
                to: 5,
                step: 1,
                round: 1,
                format: {
                    format: '0',
                    locale: 'de'
                },
                dimension: ' Kids',
            });
            var groupsize = $("#Slider").slider("value");
        </script>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var timesaved = (numkids * 65) / groupsize;
        var moneysaved = timesaved * 60;
        document.write(timesaved + "hrs            ");
        document.write("   |   " + numkids + "   |   ");
        document.write("$" + moneysaved);
    </script>
    <div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should combine all your JavaScript inside a single `<script>` tag. Your code runs now because it executes the code when the page loads. You want that code to be executed when the sliders change. Putting it in the function allows you to call that function when either of the sliders changes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function around the JavaScript that does the update and gets the values and then call this on the [slider change event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change).

```
function updateSavings() {
  var groupsize = $("#Slider").slider("value");
  var numkids = $("#SliderSingle").slider("value");
  var timesaved = (numkids*65) / groupsize;
  var moneysaved = timesaved * 60;

  document.write (timesaved + "hrs            ");
  document.write ("   |   " + numkids + "   |   ");
  document.write ("$" + moneysaved);
}

jQuery("#Slider").slider({
  change: function() { updateSavings(); }
});

jQuery("#SliderSingle").slider({
  change: function() { updateSavings(); }
});
```

You will need to change the function so that it updates a DOM element rather than writing to the document or it will keep adding text every time you change the sliders.

Comment: I'm sorry I am pretty new at this stuff. Where would I paste this code? Where do I change the function?

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I am getting close. here is what I have now. The prblem that i am having is that document.write is not working and I cannot see the time saved, money saved and number of kids.

Answer (score 0):

What are you after is the [jQuery Slider Plugin: onchangestate](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/)
I also edited your javascript code. For getting the slider value better use `val`, like:

```
jQuery("#Slider").val();
```

And for updating the text, better use `text`, like:

```
jQuery('.money_saved').text("$" + moneysaved);
```

Here is the code I have used and works as you want:

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="layout">

    <div class="layout-slider" style="width: 20%">
        <input id="SliderSingle" type="slider" name="kids" value="20" />
    </div>
    <div class="layout-slider" style="width: 20%">
        <input id="Slider" type="slider" name="group" value="20" />
    </div>

    <div class="time_saved"></div>
    <div class="money_saved"></div>
    <div class="number_kids"></div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  jQuery("#SliderSingle").slider({
    from: 1,
    to: 1000,
    step: 1,
    round: 1,
    format: {
      format: '0',
      locale: 'de'
    },
    dimension: ' Kids',
    onstatechange: function() {
      SliderChange();
    }
  });

  jQuery("#Slider").slider({
    from: 1,
    to: 5,
    step: 1,
    round: 1,
    format: {
      format: '0',
      locale: 'de'
    },
    dimension: ' Kids',
    onstatechange: function() {
      SliderChange();
    }
  });

  function SliderChange() {
    var numkids = jQuery("#SliderSingle").val();
    var groupsize = jQuery("#Slider").val();

    var timesaved = (numkids*65) / groupsize;
    var timesaved2decimal = Math.floor(timesaved * 100) / 100;

    var moneysaved = timesaved * 60;
    var moneysaved2decimal = Math.floor(moneysaved * 100) / 100;

    jQuery('.time_saved').text(timesaved2decimal + "hrs            ");
    jQuery('.number_kids').text("   |   " + numkids + "   |   ");
    jQuery('.money_saved').text("$" + moneysaved);
  }


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does not seem to be working. When I do this the document write does not work and the values are not displayed.

Comment: Yes you are right... Try my updated code. Dave Anderson's code is correct. You just have to input your data. Let me try to edit my code again...

Comment: I tried your updated code and for some reason it is still not printing the outputs. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ok!I downloaded the slider and worked this out. Check the new code. If you have any questions let me know.